# What are the settings to test a password protected URLin Selenium?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, automation, webdriver-io

Is there a way or settings in 'wdio.conf.js' file so that one can use it for  automation testing on a password protected URL.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution as to use a special URL format as base URL in wdio.conf.js file, like this: http://username:password@example.com/ -- this sends the credentials in the standard HTTP "Authorization" header.

Reference: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters